# multi store and multi stock with magento

Tags: magento

I'm using the free version of Magento and i just finished setup multi store option, so from now on this feature is working, but I didn't find the way to handle differents stock according to each multistore, for example:

- helmet#1 is only available in store-A
- helmet#2 is only available in store-B and store-C
- helmet#3 is only available in store-A and store-C but
  with differents prices ?

Can I do this with magento free edition ?

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prices cannot be specified per store, only per website and then only if you turn on the option in *System > Configuration > Catalog > Price*.

Stock can only be controlled globally - which makes sense because you either have stock or you don't. Instead change the *Status* to disabled for whichever site you wish.

Comment: I'd disagree with the Stock being controlled globally, International clients won't have the same warehouse of inventory, it's something on my wish list, Aitoc has a module for it but so far I'm not a fan of their modules.

Comment: "Stock can only be controlled globally - which makes sense because you either have stock or you don't. Instead change the Status to disabled for whichever site you wish."So i need multiple website instead of multistore to enabled the product disabled function ?

Comment: It is true the 'Status' scope is for 'website'. There are other possibilities though, for example 'Visibility' has a 'store view' scope but cannot prevent a product showing if someone types it's URL directly. It seems Magento's designers thought products' existence should be a site-level thing.

Comment: thx for your quick answer, I made a couple of try to get a "visibility" hidden product straight from the url and it doesn't show up...So would you recommend such a stock gestion or would you go for the multiple website option ? I only use multi store to handle different stock and i ve got only one domain name...

Comment: There is no harm in using multiple websites, they can even have the same domain name. It sounds odd but Magento handles it automatically with cookies.

Comment: Sorry clockworkgeek but I recently found that changing the scope to website level doesnot really makes things go the way we want to. It actually enables the admin to set different prices for different storeviews and if none of the storeviews are selected, by default it applies to All Store Views. Thank you.

Comment: anyone help me, I have 4 store and single website, how can i display all products into store 1, for inventory I have created 4 stores, now i need to display all products into store 1, and also all store products available as it is appropriate stores.

Comment: @Rathinam - That isn't relevant to this question and deserves it's own question.

Answer (score 1):

ClockworkGeek is correct, you either have the item in stock or you don't.  If you have separate stores with separate inventories you may want to think about connecting magneto with an ERP or bookkeeping software to keep track of inventory and simplify order processing and bookkeeping. This is not a programming task to be done quickly or by a single person.  There are some off the shelf extensions for a few ERPs and a few accounting apps.  QuickBooks is popular one and you may already be using it: if so here are the extensions to integrate your site with QuickBooks and make order processing a breeze(not cheap at roughly $700 for either one to handle inventories and multiple stores):

[T-Hub](http://www.atandra.com/ecommerce-quickbooks-integration-with-thub.html)

[webgility](http://www.webgility.com/store/)

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact situation as you.

In Magento SKUS are globally unique.If below extension is possible to multiple store have multiple inventory level.Please try this extension:

https://www.wyomind.com/advanced-inventory-magento.html